# How to convert a string containing spaces to an array in shell?

Tags: linux, shell

I'm trying to convert two string containing spaces to an array in shell, like so:

```
param_values=$(parse_json_with_keys)   # then, param_values: "select * from t" "terry"
```

When I convert them to an array:

```
param_values=(${param_values})
echo ${param_values[0]}  # output: "select
echo ${param_values[1]}  # output: *
```

But I expect the output:

```
echo ${param_values[0]}  # output: select * from t
echo ${param_values[1]}  # output: terry
```

It makes me confused. Could someone help me? Thanks so much!

Comment: It means, it delimits at white space and assigns it to the variable.

Comment: what is the output of parse_json_with_keys ? Are the strings from parse_json_with_keys seprated by "\n" ?

Comment: @Abis parse_json_with_keys will output: "select * from t" "terry"

Comment: @Abis the strings from parse_json_with_keys sepreated by space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I found no shorter way the following code will first delete the first and last `"`. After that the strings are separated by `" "`. To separate by that it's replaced by `#` which will be used as separator then to store into an array.
Note that `" "` and `#` is not allowed in one sub string by this method.

```
#!/bin/sh
values=$(echo '"select * from t" "terry"')
echo "$values"

echo "Remove first and last <\"> character:"
values="${values%\"}"
values="${values#\"}"
echo "$values"

echo "Replace <\" \"> by <#> and split by <#>:"
sep='" "'
IFS='#' read -r -a values <<< "${values//$sep/$'#'}"
for element in "${values[@]}"
do
    echo "$element"
done
```

**Output:**

```
$ ./stringArray.sh
"select * from t" "terry"
Remove first and last <"> character:
select * from t" "terry
Replace <" "> by <#> and split by <#>:
select * from t
terry
```